# My project doesn't compile with optimization parameters after upgrading from angular 11 to angular 12

Tags: angular, nrwl-nx

I just upgraded an environment with [nrwl](https://nrwl.io/) from angular version 11 to 12 with two angular applications and several libraries.
After update when I try to compile using optimization settings:

angular.json

```
{
 ....
 "optimization": {
    "scripts": true,
    "styles": {
       "minify": true,
       "inlineCritical": false
     },
     "fonts": true
  },
}
```

It gives me the following error (sass and scss component files):

```
/home/jose/WORK/Rental/REAL/APPS/angular-nx-ws/libs/ui-share-components/src/lib/top-panel/top-panel/top-panel.component.sass - Error: /home/jose/WORK/Rental/REAL/APPS/angular-nx-ws/libs/ui-share-components/src/lib/top-panel/top-panel/top-panel.component.sass from Css Minimizer
Error: Transform failed with 1 error:
error: Invalid version: "15.2-15.3"
    at failureErrorWithLog (/home/jose/WORK/Rental/REAL/APPS/angular-nx-ws/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:1493:15)
    at /home/jose/WORK/Rental/REAL/APPS/angular-nx-ws/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:1282:29
    at /home/jose/WORK/Rental/REAL/APPS/angular-nx-ws/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:629:9
    at handleIncomingPacket (/home/jose/WORK/Rental/REAL/APPS/angular-nx-ws/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:726:9)
    at Socket.readFromStdout (/home/jose/WORK/Rental/REAL/APPS/angular-nx-ws/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:596:7)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:309:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:284:9)
    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:223:10)
    at Pipe.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:188:23)
```

Disabling styles.minify and fonts compiles without problems:

```
"optimization": {
    "scripts": true,
    "styles": {
       "minify": false,
       "inlineCritical": false
     },
     "fonts": false
  },
}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Reason of the issue**

It is expected *browserslist* to return an entry for each version ("safari 15.2", "safari 15.3") instead of a range ("safari 15.2-15.3"). So, this is just a bug in the parsing logic of Safari browser versions which needs to be corrected and will be done soon in fixed versions of [Angular 12](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/22606#issuecomment-1026097996)/[Angular 13](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/22606#issuecomment-1025196760). Link to details is [here](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/22606#issuecomment-1025189684).

***IMPORTANT UPDATE:***

This is fixed in v12.2.16 and v13.2.1, please update if you are experiencing this issue. Users on v11 shouldn't be affected. Link to details is [here](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/22606#issuecomment-1026097996). If you can not/do not want to update for any reason, then one of the workarounds below can be used.

**Workarounds**:

***Modify .browserslistrc***

Add to *.browserslistrc* such lines:

```
not ios_saf 15.2-15.3 # temporary solution to avoid build issues https://github.com/nrwl/nx/issues/8768
not safari 15.2-15.3  # temporary solution to avoid build issues https://github.com/nrwl/nx/issues/8768
```

It has to come AFTER any mentions of ios_saf or safari. Otherwise, it doesn't work. Link to workaround is [here](https://github.com/sipcapture/homer-ui/issues/572).

***Erase content of .browserslistrc***

Erasing content of *.browserslistrc* helps to fix builds. Link to workaround is [here](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/22606#issuecomment-1025054951).

***Delete .browserslistrc***

Deletion of *.browserslistrc* helps to fix builds. Link to workaround is [here](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/22606#issuecomment-1025054951).

***Install caniuse-lite***

Add caniuse-lite package:

```
npm install caniuse-lite@1.0.30001303 --save-dev --save-exact
```

Link to workaround is [here](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/22606#issuecomment-1025517205).

Comment: Keep in mind that this is a workaround. The actual fix is yet to come.

Comment: Worked. But important - it has to come AFTER any mentions of `ios_saf` or `safari`. Otherwise it doesn't work.

Comment: @AdrianMadaras That is why I added # and comment to keep reminding myself that it is actually workaround.

Comment: @KirillGroshkov I will update the answer with your comment, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Check your `.browserslistrc` file, you can add `not ios_saf 15.2-15.3` to remove the invalid ios safari browser range. Source: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/22606#issuecomment-1025000846